# Can't connect to a port, but netstat shows what port LISTENING

Tags: c++, port, winsock

While trying to connect get error:

> *"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."*

But netstat shows:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:MY_PORT           MY_PC:0        LISTENING
```

Only problem what i can think is what app bound to the port is under step-by-step debugging, so it is paused. How i can workaround it.

Basicly i need to know somehow if somebody already bound to a port. (i can't use `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`)

---

i think i can't connect because app what uses port is in debug paused mode, so, first time i connect then it doesn't "clear connection".

Comment: And there is no firewall that could be in the way?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, good question, but i think no, both apps on the same PC, and i don't have firewall on this PC

Comment: By the way, if someone else was already using the port, then you would not be able to bind to it.

Comment: Also, you could use the `-b` option to `netstat` to show the program that is bound to the port.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, if bind not with exlusive i can bind to the same port, and i know who bound

Comment: The `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` doesn't do what you expect it to. It simply makes the end-point not available in the [`TIME_WAIT` state](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg). A port is always unique per IP-address and protocol, and can only be used by a single process at a time. Ports can _not_ be shared, and not resued while the socket is not in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: actually, socket ports can be shared and used across processes by using `DuplicateSocket()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if a given port is in use, you can `bind()` to it and check for failure.  If you don't want to create a socket and bind it, then you can instead loop through the arrays returned by the [`GetTcpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026.aspx), [`GetTcpTable2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx), [`GetTcp6Table()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309068.aspx), [`GetTcp6Table2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405.aspx), [`GetUdpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366033.aspx), and [`GetUdp6Table()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408407.aspx) functions.  The `Table2()` not only report the IPs and Ports in use, but also the Process IDs that own them (from which you can then access additional information, like file names).  These are the same functions that netstat uses internally to get its information.